# How to optimize search with create index in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, indexing

I have a database with 300,000,000 records,
To insert new records, I want to check whether the record is already in the database or not,
I use the following query to confirm:

```
SELECT student_code
FROM public.student_tbl
WHERE class_type='high_school' AND class_register='true' AND (student_code='F40101197X0' OR student_code='F40101197X1' OR student_code='F40101197X2');
```

It will take 2 minutes to complete, it takes quite a while.
Therefore, I want to save the time to check data is already in the database or not by using the following query:

```
CREATE INDEX student_tbl_class_register_index
ON public.student_tbl(class_register)
WHERE class_register IS TRUE;
```

**UPDATE1:**
*・[student_id] to [student_code]*
*・`class_type`, `student_code` are the values that can be changed, while `class_register` is deciding whether to insert new records or not, if `class_register='false'` then can insert new records.*

**UPDATE2:**
As the answer of *Gordon Linoff*, *Laurenz Albe*, *ex4* suggested (thanks for your support),
I update as below:

Query check whether the data already exists in the database or not:

```
SELECT student_code
FROM public.student_tbl
WHERE class_type = 'high_school' AND
      class_register = 'true' AND
      student_code IN ('F40101197X0', 'F40101197X1', 'F40101197X2');
```

Query creates the index:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX CONCURRENTLY studenttbl_classtype_studentcode_idx
ON public.student_tbl (class_type, student_code)
WHERE class_register = 'true';

ALTER TABLE public.student_tbl
ADD CONSTRAINT studenttbl_classtype_studentcode_idx
UNIQUE USING INDEX studenttbl_classtype_studentcode_idx;
```

Is it okay with the **CREATE INDEX** statement above?
Or how can I do well in this case, please tell me!
Any hint will be great.
Thanks!

Comment: Don't keep modifying the question by adding parts of the answer. You cannot have a constraint with a partial index. Test yourself!

Answer (score 1):

For this query:

```
SELECT student_id
FROM public.student_tbl
WHERE class_type = 'high_school' AND
      class_register = 'true' AND
      student_id IN ('F40101197X0', 'F40101197X1', 'F40101197X2');
```

You want an index on `student_tbl(class_type, class_register, student_id)`.

However, if you want to guarantee that rows are not duplicated, then you should be using a unique index or constraint.

Comment: Thanks for your support!
Does this mean that I need to create indexes for all 3 fields as `student_tbl(class_type, class_register, student_id)`, right?

Comment: I think last note in this answer has best solution. Use unique index if you want something to be unique in your database.

Comment: Thanks for your support! I have updated the question.